# Twitter Bootstrap: Get selector value from popover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, selector, popover

If I define selector option while creating popover. How can i check what is selector value for popover ? In other words, Can I get options object associated with that particular popover ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little unsure of what you are asking.

for your 3rd question on whether or not you can get options of a specific popover you can do something like

```
var options = {
 //your popover options
}

$('#selector').popover(options);

var $popover = $('#selector').data('popover');

console.log($popover.options);
```

**UPDATE FOR BS 3**

the data attribute is now namespaced

`var $popover = $('#selector').data('bs.popover');`

Comment: awesome! this would be var $popover = $('#selector').data('bs.popover');
 in the current version of bootstrap i.e 3.x.
Further has attributes for $element(the triggering element), $tip (the actual popover element) and $arrow.